# Multi-line chapter with different font sizes in report class

Tags: fonts, chapters

I'm using the `report` class to write a book and want the chapter titles to be spread across multiple lines with the ability to select a font size for each line.

```
\documentclass{report}


\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  %%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
  {\parindent \z@ \center \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %%%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
  {\parindent \z@ \center
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter*{\textbf{ŚirīharṣaMahākaviPraṇītam\\Naiṣadhīyacaritam\\Saralavyākhyāsahitam\\prathamaḥ sargaḥ}}

%Want to set different font sizes for different lines as below:
{\small ŚirīharṣaMahākaviPraṇītam}\\
{\Huge Naiṣadhīyacaritam}\\
Saralavyākhyāsahitam\\
{\Large prathamaḥ sargaḥ}


\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

How can this be done? I prefer not to change the `documentclass` because it may cause other unknown changes to my document (already ~600 pages long).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost provided the answer yourself.

```
% chapterprob.tex  SE 596976
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  %%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
  {\parindent \z@ \center \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %%%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
  {\parindent \z@ \center
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%\chapter*{\textbf{ŚirīharṣaMahākaviPraṇītam\\Naiṣadhīyacaritam\\Saralavyākhyāsahitam\\prathamaḥ sargaḥ}}

\chapter*{\textbf{{\small ŚirīharṣaMahākaviPraṇītam}\\
 {\Huge Naiṣadhīyacaritam}\\
 {\normalsize Saralavyākhyāsahitam}\\
 {\Large prathamaḥ sargaḥ}}}

%Want to set different font sizes for different lines as below:
{\small ŚirīharṣaMahākaviPraṇītam}\\
{\Huge Naiṣadhīyacaritam}\\
Saralavyākhyāsahitam\\
{\Large prathamaḥ sargaḥ}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That was easier than I thought. Thanks!